# Excel SUMPRODUCT w/ COUNTIF Between 2 Dates and 2nd Criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A2:A1048576,ROW(INDIRECT(DATE(2019,1,1)&":"&DATE(2019,1,31))))>0)+0)
```

which will add up the unique occurrences between two dates.  But I want to add a second criteria for a different column, lets say column "C" and it must contain lets say "*TEST*" in the cell.  How would I modify this formula?  I believe it uses COUNTIFS, but I can't seem to get the formula to work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

```
Date    Quantity    Notes
1/11/2019   2   OTHER Member Number Corrections
1/14/2019   7   TEST Member Number Corrections
1/14/2019   222 TEST Member Merges
1/15/2019   5   TEST Member Number Corrections
```

So the answer should be 2, they are both in January, 1/1/2019 - 1/31/2019 and they occurred on only two days, and the formula disregarded that there are blank cells at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry tried the quick fix but will not work.  The formula you want is large and convoluted.  I do not have the time at them moment to write it up.  If this is still open when I do have the time I will try to answer.

Comment: Appreciate it thank you!

Comment: Here is the formula that finally worked:     {=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY( IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TEST",C2:C100)), IF((A2:A100>=DATE(2019,1,1))*(A2:A100<=DATE(2019,1,31)), MATCH(A2:A100,A2:A100,0))), ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),1))}